# Kafka consumerConfig in Java isn't set

Tags: java, spring-boot, ssl, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have the following Consumer setting is java spring:

Consumer config (variables are taken from the abstract class):

```
@EnableKafka
@Configuration
public class KafkaConsumerConfig extends KafkaConnectorAbs {

    @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> consumerConfig(){
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "0");
        props.put("security.protocol", securityProtocol);
        props.put("ssl.truststore.location", trustStoreLocation);
        props.put("ssl.truststore.password", trustStorePassword);
        props.put("ssl.keystore.location", keytStoreLocation);
        props.put("ssl.keystore.password", keytStorePassword);

        return props;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfig());
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String>> factory(
            ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory
    ){
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        return factory;
    }
}
```

application.yml:

```
spring:
  kafka:
    bootstrap-servers: localhost:9092
  security:
    protocol: "SSL"
  ssl:
    trust-store-location: <path>\java.truststore.jks
    trust-store-password: Pass
    key-store-location:  <path>\java.keystore.jks
    key-store-password: Pass
```

Listener:

```
@Component
public class KafkaListeners {

    @KafkaListener(
            topicPartitions = @TopicPartition(
                    topic = "foo",
                    partitionOffsets = { @PartitionOffset(partition = "0", initialOffset = "0") }),
            groupId = "0"
    )
    void readMessages(String msg){

        System.out.println("Incoming message: " + msg);
    }
}
```

And I got the following logs:

```
2022-08-26 17:21:15.300  INFO 17984 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-0-1, groupId=0] Node -1 disconnected.
2022-08-26 17:21:15.301  INFO 17984 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-0-1, groupId=0] Cancelled in-flight API_VERSIONS request with correlation id 1 due to node -1 being disconnected (elapsed time since creation: 378ms, elapsed time since send: 378ms, request timeout: 30000ms)
2022-08-26 17:21:15.301  WARN 17984 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-0-1, groupId=0] Bootstrap broker localhost:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected
```

Also when I check the logs I realised my consumer settings are not considered (keystore and trustore values are null...):

```
    2022-08-26 17:21:14.826  INFO 17984 --- [           main] o.a.k.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig    : ConsumerConfig values: 
...
        ssl.cipher.suites = null
        ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2]
        ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
        ssl.engine.factory.class = null
        ssl.key.password = null
        ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
        ssl.keystore.certificate.chain = null
        ssl.keystore.key = null
        ssl.keystore.location = null
        ssl.keystore.password = null
        ssl.keystore.type = JKS
        ssl.protocol = TLSv1.2
        ssl.provider = null
        ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
        ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
        ssl.truststore.certificates = null
        ssl.truststore.location = null
        ssl.truststore.password = null
        ssl.truststore.type = JKS
        value.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
```

Any idea what's going here? I have similar setting for Producer and it is working...

--- UPDATE ---
There is a class, called KafkaConnectorAbs, where I wire up the config variables:

```
@Value("${spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers}")
protected String bootstrapServers;

@Value(value = "${spring.security.protocol}")
protected String securityProtocol;

@Value(value = "${spring.ssl.trust-store-location}")
protected String trustStoreLocation;

@Value(value = "${spring.ssl.trust-store-password}")
protected String trustStorePassword;

@Value(value = "${spring.ssl.key-store-location}")
protected String keytStoreLocation;

@Value(value = "${spring.ssl.key-store-password}")
protected String keytStorePassword;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have set `spring.ssl...` and `spring.security.protocol` in the YAML. Indentation and nesting matter.

You should set the actual consumer properties

```yaml
spring:
  kafka:
    consumer:
      properties:
        "[security.protocol]": SSL
        ...
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/messaging.html#messaging.kafka.additional-properties

Comment: Thank you for your response! I tried this out, but it didn't help. I don't see the configuration is loaded...

Comment: Can you please edit your question to show how variables are wired into your config class?